# why cannot render app to the screen and getting "cannot call a class as a function error"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render my ClockApp component but I get this error and can not render it to the screen.
My app component is class component and others are stateless functional components.
this same code worked in codepen without problems so did I miss something regarding importing the components from right directorys? 
Thanks already.

**Code**

Timer component

````
Timer component

function Timer(props) {

    return (
        <div className="timer">
          <h2 id="timer-label">{props.name}</h2>
          <span id="time-left">{props.time}</span>
          <div className="controls">
            <button 
              id="start_stop"
              onClick={props.onPlayPause}>&#8227;&#8214;
            </button>
            <button 
              id="reset" 
              onClick={props.onReset}>&#8634;
            </button>
          </div>  
        </div>
    )
}

export default Timer

TimerSettings component

function TimerSettings(props) {
  return (
    <div className="timer-settings">
      <h3 id={`${props.label}-label`}>
        {props.label === "session" ? "Session " : "Break "}Length
      </h3>
      <div className="timer-buttons">
        <button
          id={`${props.label}-decrement`}
          onClick={() => props.handleClick(`${props.label}Value`, false)}
        >
          &darr;
        </button>
        <div id={`${props.label}-length`}>{props.value}</div>
        <button
          id={`${props.label}-increment`}
          onClick={() => props.handleClick(`${props.label}Value`, true)}
        >
          &uarr;
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TimerSettings;

ClockApp Component

import React from "react";
import Timer from "./timer";
import TimerSettings from "./timer-settings";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import "./App.css";

class ClockApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breakValue: 5,
      sessionValue: 25,
      currentTimer: "Session",
      timeLeft: 1500000,
      going: false,
      changedLength: false
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.timeLeft === 0 && prevState.currentTimer === "Session") {
      this.setState({
        timeLeft: this.state.breakValue * 60 * 1000,
        currentTimer: "Break"
      });
      this.audio.play();
    }
    if (prevState.timeLeft === 0 && prevState.currentTimer === "Break") {
      this.setState({
        timeLeft: this.state.sessionValue * 60 * 1000,
        currentTimer: "Session"
      });
      this.audio.play();
    }
  }

  handleTimers = (label, inc) => {
    if (this.state[label] === 60 && inc) return undefined;
    if (this.state[label] === 1 && !inc) return undefined;
    this.setState({
      [label]: this.state[label] + (inc ? 1 : -1)
    });
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      breakValue: 5,
      sessionValue: 25,
      currentTimer: "Session",
      timeLeft: 1500000,
      going: false,
      changedLength: false
    });
    this.audio.pause();
    this.audio.currentTime = 0;
    clearInterval(this.clock);
  };

  handleTimerStatus = () => {
    this.setState({ going: !this.state.going });
    if (this.state.going) {
      clearInterval(this.clock);
      this.setState({ going: false });
    } else {
      if (this.state.changedLength) {
        this.clock = setInterval(
          () => this.setState({ timeLeft: this.state.timeLeft - 1000 }),
          1000
        );
        this.setState({ going: true });
      } else {
        this.setState(
          {
            timeLeft: this.state.sessionValue * 60 * 1000,
            changedLength: true,
            going: true
          },
          () => {
            return (this.clock = setInterval(
              () => this.setState({ timeLeft: this.state.timeLeft - 1000 }),
              1000
            ));
          }
        );
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
        <TimerSettings
          value={this.state.breakValue}
          label="break"
          handleClick={this.handleTimers}
        />
        <TimerSettings
          value={this.state.sessionValue}
          label="session"
          handleClick={this.handleTimers}
        />
        <Timer
          name={this.state.currentTimer}
          time={Moment(this.state.timeLeft).format("mm:ss")}
          onReset={this.handleReset}
          onPlayPause={this.handleTimerStatus}
        />
        <audio
          id="beep"
          src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/benjaminadk/Data+synth+beep+high+and+sweet.mp3"
          ref={element => (this.audio = element)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ClockApp;

Index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import ClockApp from './clockapp';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<ClockApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();

Error


TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
Anonymous function
C:/Users/Jari/Desktop/pomodoro-clock/node_modules/react-moment/dist/index.js:892
  889 | function t(e) {
  890 |   var n, r, o;
  891 |   return function (e, t) {
> 892 |     if (!(e instanceof t)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
      | ^
  893 |   }(this, t), r = this, o = m(t).call(this, e), n = !o || "object" !== s(o) && "function" != typeof o ? f(r) : o, h(f(n), "setTimer", function () {
  894 |     var e = n.props.interval;
  895 |     n.clearTimer(), t.pooledTimer || 0 === e || (n.timer = setInterval(function () {
View compiled
t


C:/Users/Jari/Desktop/pomodoro-clock/node_modules/react-moment/dist/index.js:891
  888 |   S = function (e) {
  889 | function t(e) {
  890 |   var n, r, o;
> 891 |   return function (e, t) {
      | ^
  892 |     if (!(e instanceof t)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
  893 |   }(this, t), r = this, o = m(t).call(this, e), n = !o || "object" !== s(o) && "function" != typeof o ? f(r) : o, h(f(n), "setTimer", function () {
  894 |     var e = n.props.interval;


View compiled
ClockApp.prototype.render
C:/Users/Jari/Desktop/pomodoro-clock/src/clockapp.js:90
  87 | };
  88 | 
  89 | render() {
> 90 |   return (
     | ^
  91 |     <div>
  92 |       <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
  93 |       <TimerSettings```
````

Comment: A demo in a Codesandbox would help to test your app. But I think the problem is that you're using `react-moment` and you should use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) directly. You're calling a React component and that's what the error message is telling you. The location in question is the prop `time={Moment(this.state.timeLeft).format("mm:ss")}` at your `Timer` JSX markup.

Comment: ooh man that was it. instead of importing from the moment I imported from the react moment. thank you very much.